error opening "chromedriver" in "jupyter"
Good day to all,
I am making a program to open a specific page in Chrome, when calling "chromedriver" I get the following error:
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('webdriver//chromedriver.exe')

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
  Cell In[4], line 1
  ----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome('webdriver//chromedriver.exe')

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-      packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:45, in WebDriver.__init__(self, options,    service, keep_alive)
       42 service = service if service else Service()
       43 options = options if options else Options()
  ---> 45 super().__init__(
       46     browser_name=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["browserName"],
       47     vendor_prefix="goog",
       48     options=options,
       49     service=service,
       50     keep_alive=keep_alive,
       51 )

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-     packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:50, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self,     browser_name, vendor_prefix, options, service, keep_alive)
       47 self.service = service
       49 finder = DriverFinder(self.service, options)
  ---> 50 if finder.get_browser_path():
       51     options.binary_location = finder.get_browser_path()
       52     options.browser_version = None
 
  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-    packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py:47, in DriverFinder.get_browser_path(self)
       46 def get_browser_path(self) -> str:
  ---> 47     return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
  
  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-    packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py:56, in DriverFinder._binary_paths(self)
       53 if self._paths["driver_path"]:
       54     return self._paths
  ---> 56 browser = self._options.capabilities["browserName"]
       57 try:
       58     path = self._service.path
  
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

como puedo solucionar este error, agradezco mucho su colaboración.

You are not implementing the arguments properly. You need to feed in the location of the chromedriver binary.
Try this.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

In case you didn't know you can download the binary from here. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
